# Displaying url parameter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, heroku

I am building a VERY simple ruby test application, just to see how it works, but I'm already stuck in overly complex tutorials.

Say that my ruby app is running at heroku at : http://example.herokuapp.com
And that I am calling it like this: http://example.herokuapp.com/test=3 or perhaps http://example.herokuapp.com/page.rb?test=3 ?

How do I get the value from "test" in my ruby output?
My Heroku demo code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "The value of test is..."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sinatra the route patterns may consist of named parameters. These parameters can be accessed using the params hash.You need to do something like this:

```
get '/:test' do
  "The value of test is...#{params[:test]}"
end
```

Url:

```
 http://example.herokuapp.com/3
```